# How to configure spring-integration-sftp to move a remote file after it has been downloaded to local filesystem?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have the following kotlin configuration for sftp file sync with a remote server.

```
@Bean
fun sessionFactory(): SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> {
    val factory = DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true)
    factory.setHost(sftpHost)
    factory.setPort(sftpPort.toInt())
    factory.setUser(sftpUser)
    factory.setPassword(sftpPasword)
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true)
    return CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>(factory)
}

@Bean
fun template(): SftpRemoteFileTemplate {
    return SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sessionFactory())
}

@Bean
fun sftpInboundFileSynchronizer(): SftpInboundFileSynchronizer {
    val fileSynchronizer = SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sessionFactory())
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false)
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload)
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore(), "downloaded"))
    return fileSynchronizer
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "download", poller = [Poller(cron = "0/5 * * * * *")])
fun sftpMessageSource(): MessageSource<File> {
    val source = SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer())
    source.setLocalDirectory(File(sftpLocalDirectoryDownload))
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
    source.setLocalFilter(FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore(), "downloaded"))
    return source
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "download", outputChannel = "move")
fun resultFileHandler(): MessageHandler {
    return MessageHandler { message -> publisher.handleMessage(message) }
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "move")
fun sftpOutboundGateway(sessionFactory: SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>): SftpOutboundGateway {
    val gateway = SftpOutboundGateway(sessionFactory, "mv", "payload")
    gateway.setOutputChannelName("errorChannel")
    return gateway
}
```

What I would like to do is move the file after it has been downloaded from the remote server; however, I have not found a way that works. Most examples are using xml configurations.

Everything is working to the `resultFileHandler` method call where I can process the local file; however the MessageHandler is not getting sent to the `move` channel. I am wondering what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using 3 outbound gateways instead

```
...LSgateway->splitter->GETgateway->process->MVgateway
```

The [ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp) shows a similar technique, but with RM rather than MV (although is uses XML configuration because it's quite old).